# How to connect the points in such a way that a parallelogram is created

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, coordinates

I have four coordinates in my `df` table:

| lat1 | lon1 | lat2 | lon2 | lat3 | lon3 | lat4 | lon4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51.071833 | 6.237204 | 51.071836 | 6.237195 | 51.071833 | 6.237195 | 51.071836 | 6.237204 |

Based on this data, I try to connect the points in such a way that a parallelogram is created.

Scatter plot:

```
# selecting columns start with 'lat'
xx = df[[col for col in test if col.startswith('lat')]].stack().to_list() 
# selecting columns start with 'lon'
yy = df[[col for col in test if col.startswith('lon')]].stack().to_list() 

plt.scatter(xx,yy)
```

[image]

Unfortunatelly, when I try to connect points with lines, it doesn't work:

```
plt.scatter(xx,yy)
plt.plot(xx,yy)
```

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I guess it's because the points are not ordered. I also tried this:

```
points = np.c_[xx, yy]

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
clf = NearestNeighbors(2).fit(points)
G = clf.kneighbors_graph()

import networkx as nx
T = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(G)

order = list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(T, 0))

xx = xx[order]
yy = yy[order]

plt.plot(xx, yy)
plt.show()
```

But it is still incorrect.

Do you have idea where is the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the [convex hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) of the four points:

```python
import numpy as np
points=np.column_stack((xx,yy))

from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
hull = ConvexHull(points)
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'k-')
```

Result:

[image: convex hull]